# Is password is sent as text in this after submitting PHP?

Tags: php

i was searching about simple hashing with passwords in login form.
i came across this http://tinsology.net/2009/06/creating-a-secure-login-system-the-right-way/. here he hashes the password, creates a salt, and then again hashes the password & salt.
I am building a login form myself, this is abc.php

```
<form name="register" action="register.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" />
Password Again: <input type="password" name="pass2" />
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

after submitting goes to,  register.php, it has

```
$u=$_REQUEST['username'];
$p=$_REQUEST['pass1'];
//salt create function
//hashing code
//final hash password
```

and then submitting $u & 'final password' in the database.

Q: my question is when submitting the form from abc.php, does the password goes as text?

and if yes, then there is a chance of someone reading it, and then what's the need of hashing passwords, because even when i login, i will submit the page, and retrieve the pass and username from $_REQUEST on maybe another page, where it will be checked, it travelled as text, and thus can be read by someone.

Comment: There are two problems with passwords: storage and transmission. Storage is the most critical, you *must* hash stored passwords. Protecting it during transmission is a good idea as well, but not as important. It's a lot easier to hack a server and read the entire database, than to insert yourself somewhere in the middle of every HTTP request to/from the server to log the passwords. So, hashing (as described in this article) is a necessity. But if you have the means, then you should put your entire login area under SSL/https. The code sample here will be perfectly secure if SSL is active.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The password is now sent in clear text. There is a workaround without the use of HTTPS. You can hash the password before it is sent over the HTTP socket with javascript. There are several tutorials out there. This isn't as good as using https but still better than nothing.

Answer (score 6):

Your password is sent via HTTP Post or HTTP Get, depends on method in your form.
HTTP Post or HTTP Get is sent via socket stream and someone can sniff your data along the way, your network admin, your ISP provider, etc.

If you want to create secure login, your server must support HTTPS.
If you sent via HTTPS, no one can read your data.

Answer (score 2):

The "secure" part of that article clearly relates to the storage of the password. Someone could intercept the password if the network on the client or the server side is not secure (i.e. someone with a packet sniffer on the network).

If this is a concern, you can mitigate that risk by using SSL, which will encrypt the conversation between client and server.

Answer (score 2):

If the user submits your form the browser sends the password as part of the post request.

If you are using SSL (https) the complete communication between the browser and your webserver is encrypted (so the data can not be read by a third party), but if you are using http anyone who can see the traffic, can see the password

Answer (score 2):

The code you're referring to is only about password storage, so yes, the password will go over the Internet in clear text and yes, someone may intercept it at for example a WiFi hotspot.

Your best, most proven solution is to use SSL for login communication.